# Inclusion of constraint

Tags: z3

Given non-negative real number `tSS, tLS, tIS, tBS`.
(i.e. they are real type with tSS>=0 and tLS>=0 and tIS>=0 and tBS>=0 and tSS>=0)

The following contraint C1 is in CNF format that contains 12 conjuncts.

```
(tSS+tLS<=tIS)And(tIS<=tBS)And(tSS+tLS+tIS+tBS<=3) OR
(tSS+tLS<=tBS)And(tBS<=tIS)And(tSS+tLS+tIS+tBS<=3) OR
(tSS+tLS<=tBS)And(tSS<=tIS)And(tIS<=tSS+tLS)And(tSS+tLS+tIS+tBS<=3) OR
(tSS<=tIS)And(tIS<=tBS)And(tBS<=tSS+tLS)And(tSS+tLS+tIS+tBS<=3) OR
(tSS+tLS<=tIS)And(tSS<=tBS)And(tBS<=tSS+tLS)And(tSS+tLS+tIS+tBS<=3) OR
(tSS<=tBS)And(tBS<=tIS)And(tIS<=tSS+tLS)And(tSS+tLS+tIS+tBS<=3) OR
(tSS+tLS<=tBS)And(tIS<=tSS)And(tSS+tLS+tIS+tBS<=3) OR
(tSS<=tBS)And(tIS<=tBS)And(tBS<=tSS+tLS)And(tSS+tLS+tIS+tBS<=3) OR
(tIS<=tBS)And(tBS<=tSS)And(tSS+tLS+tIS+tBS<=3) OR
(tSS+tLS<=tIS)And(tBS<=tSS)And(tSS+tLS+tIS+tBS<=3) OR
(tSS<=tIS)And(tBS<=tSS)And(tIS<=tSS+tLS)And(tSS+tLS+tIS+tBS<=3) OR
(tIS<=tSS)And(tBS<=tIS)And(tSS+tLS+tIS+tBS<=3)
```

I wish to obtain the constraint C2 in the form of

```
tSS<=a and tLS<=b and tIS<=c and tBS <=d and tSS<=e
```

The constraint C2 only needs to be included in C1, i.e.
any valuation satisfies C2 must satisfies C1, but not vice versa.
The value of a-e, is value that ranges from 0 to infinity.
Infinity means that it can take any value larger than 0.

Is it possible to use Z3 to infer the value of a-e? (it can be unsatisfiable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be more efficient techniques to do it but at least you can solve the problem using quantifiers.

Let `C1(tSS, tLS, tIS, tBS)` denote the CNF formula and `C2(SS, tLS, tIS, tBS, a, b, c, d)` is the constraint to satisfy. You can check for satisfiability of the following quantified formula:

`forall tSS tLS tIS tBS. C2(SS, tLS, tIS, tBS, a, b, c, d) => C1(tSS, tLS, tIS, tBS)`

where `a, b, c, d` are free variables.

I encoded your concrete example [using Z3 SMT online](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/plXYW). The query is unsatisfiable in this case.

Comment: But tSS+tLS+tIS+tBS<=3 is an inequality for every conjuncts, therefore take tSS=4, tLS=4, tIS=4, and tBS=4 seems will make the inequality false. I am not sure why the result is a = b = c = d = 4.0?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question carefully. I updated the answer and the link accordingly.